# Variable substitution in bump function

Tags: real-analysis

I have run into a small issue trying to solve an exercise involving a bump function.

[image]

[image]

My problem is with (d). I have shown that

$$
\phi_{n, \varepsilon}(t)=
 \begin{cases}
     c_n 
     \left(
      \frac{t-(t_0-\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon \varepsilon^\frac{1}{2n}}
     \right)^n   
     \left(
      \frac{(\varepsilon+t_0)-t}{\varepsilon \varepsilon^\frac{1}{2n}}
     \right)^n & \text{for} \ a \leq t \leq b \\
             0 & \text{otherwise}              
 \end{cases}
$$

In order to remove the terms $\frac{t}{\varepsilon \varepsilon^\frac{1}{2n}}$I wanted to substitute $t \to t \varepsilon \varepsilon^\frac{1}{2n}$ which yields the expression

$$
c_n 
 \left(
  t-\frac{t_0-\varepsilon}{\varepsilon \varepsilon^\frac{1}{2n}}
 \right)^n   
 \left(
  \frac{(\varepsilon+t_0)}{\varepsilon \varepsilon^\frac{1}{2n}}-t
 \right)^n   
$$

which is already close to the needed expression. Since the function is supposed to vanish at $t=a$ and $t=b$ I considered

$$
a-\frac{t_0-\varepsilon}{\varepsilon \varepsilon^\frac{1}{2n}}=0 
$$

$$
\frac{(\varepsilon+t_0)}{\varepsilon \varepsilon^\frac{1}{2n}}-b=0.
$$.

Adding and subtracting the last two equations yields conditions for $t_0, \varepsilon$. But I am concerned about the variable substitution which doesn't seem quite right to me. Am I actually on the correct track here?

Comment: Is it not enough to match the support of $\phi_{n, \epsilon}$ (which is $(t_0-\epsilon, t_0+\epsilon)$) with $(a,b)$, i.e. solve $t_0 = (a+b)/2$ and $2\epsilon = b-a$?